# How do I compare my Query performance in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, query-performance

I have complex queries in BigQuery that I can modify to optimize further. (I am using the GCP console to run these queries)
However, I unable to test if my changes are actually improving the performance.

I am checking the execution details to understand the performance and I expected "Slot Time Consumed" to be a comparable metric. But the execution details seem to be inconsistent.

Running the same query twice:

[image: Run1]

[image: Run2]

Is there any other way or a tool I can use to compare query performances consistently over time?

Comment: did you have chance to click on that link called "Learn more"?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - I did. Per that documentation, slot time should be representative of computational work done by the query, which is why I would want to use it as a comparable metric. But it seems to be inconsistent for the same query, and that confused me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to optimize?  Time or amount of data consumed?  Both are worth something to you, but data usage has a direct cost.

Comment: Primarily I'm trying to optimize time here. The queries I'm comparing consume pretty much the same amount of data and give me the same output.

Comment: Time will be harder to optimize at this level of granularity.  Because BQ is a shared/cloud resource, there might or might not be many other jobs running on the same hardware simultaneously, so the difference in slot-times in your example could just be random fluctuation.  In general, optimizations against data usage (partitions, clusters, minimizing columns scanned, minimizing joins, etc) will see benefits in time reduction as well.

Comment: I understand that "Elapsed Time" can be different, due to the reasons you mentioned. Per BQ: "A slot is a unit of computational capacity required to execute SQL queries". So, I don't understand why the computational capacity required, would change for the same query.
In short, I am looking for a way to benchmark the Time Complexity of my queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the query plan and timeline](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) to analyze and compare a query performance and focusing in the steps that are taking more time to be processed and try to optimize them; however, keep in mind that the query performance could vary according to resource availability. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview) you can find recommendation to improve the performance of your queries.

On the other hand, regarding the slot time utilization, when BigQuery executes a query job, it converts the declarative SQL statement into a graph of execution, broken up into a series of query stages, which themselves are composed of more granular sets of execution steps. BigQuery leverages a heavily distributed parallel architecture to run these queries, and the stages model the units of work that many potential workers may execute in parallel. BigQuery query execution is dynamic, which means that the query plan can be modified while a query is in flight. Stages that are introduced while a query is running are often used to improve data distribution throughout query workers. Whenever a new query is submitted, capacity is automatically re-allocated across executing queries. Individual units of work can be gracefully paused, resumed, and queued up as more capacity becomes available to each query.

Based on that, BigQuery does not guarantee that the slot time consumed will be the same all the times you execute a query as this will depend on the status of the resources and their availability. I recommend you take a look at [the query execution using slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots#query_execution_using_slots), [the query execution under slot resource economy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots#query_execution_under_slot_resource_economy) and [the fair scheduling in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots#fair_scheduling_in_bigquery)  documentations where you can find an explanation on how BigQuery process the queries.